# creating random number and use it as code

Tags: batch-file, random

```
echo You found secret option! Your code is %random%. >> notepad.txt
```

I want to use this as a code generator. Code that was generated will need to be used in cmd to continue process.

Comment: This is extremely unclear. *What* is your "problem with this code"?

Comment: it's creating a txt file. There is generated code. And I want to use this code from generated txt file in cmd to proceed next commands. If user write wrong code the cmd will close. My problem is in reading this generated code from txt file and saving it to use in cmd

Comment: You would need to show the code that you have written and state what the problem with that code is. If you haven't written any of the relevant code yet and are at the stage of having a somewhat vague idea of what you would like your code to do, this question is too broad.

Comment: that is all of my code. I just want to know what command is for reading specific text from notepad and using it

Comment: Why would write out to a file and then read it back into use it?  If you are going to use this code within another batch file then you would just assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off your original non-edited request I made a script that does exactly what you requested. You fist need to read the data off your text file to check if it already has a code on it or not. This can be done by firstly reading the file with `set /p mytextfile=< %~dp0notepad.txt` then checking if its blank using `IF "%mytextfile%"==""`.

Instead of putting the `%random%` inside your echo, we can set it as a string that can be called upon and extracted to a text file using `echo %number% >> notepad.txt`.

To call the password into variable we can use `set /p password=< %~dp0notepad.txt`. This will read the text document and set `%password%` as the string. Then using another `IF` statement, we can compare the results and have it check if your password is correct or not.

Please keep in mind the `%~dp0` is simply the path of the batch location. Change your path as needed.

```
@ECHO OFF

IF NOT EXIST %~dp0notepad.txt (type nul >notepad.txt)

set /p mytextfile=< %~dp0notepad.txt 
IF "%mytextfile%"=="" (Goto empty) else (goto exist)

:empty
echo File is empty! Generating code!
set number=%random%
echo %number% >> notepad.txt
echo You found secret option! Your code is %number%.
pause
goto exist

:exist
cls
set /p password=< %~dp0notepad.txt
set /p attempt=Enter your code to continue: 
IF "%password%"=="%attempt% " (goto unlocked) else (goto exist)

:unlocked
cls
echo do stuff
pause
```

Comment: thanks. I will have it in mind and code works brilliant.

Comment: Note: `echo %number% >> notepad.txt` writes a trailing space to the file (and later `set /p` will read that space too. This is handled with `IF "%password%"=="%attempt% " (` here, but a better approach is to not write the space in the first place. Use alternative syntax `>file.txt echo %number%` or `(echo %number%)>file.txt`